# Nuclide vs Atom-IDE

Tags: python, ide, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

What is the practical difference between the Nuclide package for Atom and the Atom-IDE package? I'm only a novice Python programmer, and all I can piece together is that Atom-IDE is built from Nuclide, but they both seem to have similar features and language support.

Comment: Nuclide is not open source while Atom is. Atom-IDE is just add-ons for Atom.

Comment: @will7200 Nuclide is open source https://github.com/facebook/nuclide

Comment: @Jordan Eldredge according to here, https://atom.io/packages/nuclide, says that it should not be considered an open source licence.

Comment: True, it's a confusing distinction. The source code is freely available, but you are correct, it is not truly "open source". Thanks for calling that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atom IDE contains a subset of Nuclide’s functionality. Specifically, it contains the set of features needed to support language servers (https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/). It’s maintained by the Nuclide team.

Source: I am a member of the Nuclide team.

Comment: So, for basic Python scripting and debugging, it sounds like Atom IDE is plenty. I don't do any web development; I just use it for structural engineering problems.

Comment: @AndyPerez Yeah. It sounds like Atom IDE is going to be a better fit for you!